# Look up in XML-file using an array and create new array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have an array - like this:

```
Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def [2] => ghi )
```

And I have an XML-file - like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ROOT>
  <SECTION>
    <PART1>abc</PART1>
    <PART2>111</PART2>
    <PART3>222</PART3>
  </SECTION>
  <SECTION>
    <PART1>def</PART1>
    <PART2>333</PART2>
    <PART3>444</PART3>
  </SECTION>
  <SECTION>
    <PART1>ghi</PART1>
    <PART2>555</PART2>
    <PART3>666</PART3>
  </SECTION>
</ROOT>
```

What I need is to look up all the values of the array in the XML-file PART1 and output PART2 in a new array that then would look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 333 [2] => 555 )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some of your code and we will help you as good as we can. Please keep in mind, that StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Fair enough. I have tried a foreach loop - like this: foreach ($xml->children() as $output) { if ($output->PART1 == $array) { $part2 = $output->PART2 }}

Answer (score 0):

With [**`SimpleXMLElement`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class:

```
$arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($your_xmlfile);
$part2 = [];

foreach ($sxe->SECTION as $s) {
    if (in_array($s->PART1, $arr)) $part2[] = (string) $s->PART2;
}
print_r($part2);
```

The output:

```
Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 333 [2] => 555 )
```

Comment: I have tried RomanPerekrest' suggestion and added { } around $part2[] = (string) $s->PART2; but the result is Array ( ) - an empty array...

Comment: @McClaud, check your code for errors and make sure you are using a valid xml

Comment: I have found the error - and it ain't the XML-file. It's the array ($arr). My array is created in another foreach-loop and looks like this: `foreach ($fixturesarray as $value) { if ($i++ % 9 == 4) { $arr[] = $value; }}`. How to make the array available in the foreach loop you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values from the array to create Xpath expression, that fetch the values you want:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$keys = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

$result = [];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
  $result[] = $xpath->evaluate('string(/ROOT/SECTION[PART1="'.$key.'"]/PART2)');
}

var_dump($result);
```